# Mechanical Turk - API created hits are not shown under batches

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've created around a few hundred HITs using a Python API, but they aren't shown under the manage -> results.

[image]

Is there a way to view HITs created by Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to see HITs created through the API (regardless of language used) was removed from the website in December 2017. This blog post describes a workaround, using the AWS CLI, to see these HITs.

https://blog.mturk.com/upcoming-changes-to-the-mturk-requester-website-and-questionform-data-format-f7c3238be58c